How to download a file storaged in Google Cloud using only a URL with file's view
I only have a link from a file storaged in the URL https://storage.googleapis.com/ (I understand that it is Google Cloud), this link shows me the file in the browser and I can download it manually.
I want to download it automatically, but I do not know how to do it.
Putting the URL into a Postman Get request, the params I get from URL are these:

GoogleAccessId
Signature
Expires

I have tried to execute the Get request with curl into a Windows CMD, with the option -o directory_path to download the output as a PDF file. My petition is the next one:
path_with_my_curl_file -X GET "https://storage.googleapis.com/..." -H "content-type: multipart/form-data;" -H "Authorization: Bearer Token" -o "C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\file.pdf" 

But I get a corrupt file.
I would appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

Check the output you got. It could be a few things. It might be an error message as an XML doc explaining that something is wrong. Alternately, perhaps the object is compressed or something and is not a regular PDF file? GCS won't send you random, corrupt data, so the nature of the data you got should give you a hint about the nature of your problem.

Consider trying again with Private Browsing. Your browser may be providing required credentials automatically.
